# Can't access Gpus_all_regions in Quotas. Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, quota

When I search for gpus_all_regions, I do find it but it's gray and I can't click on it. Also there is a show-box with "?" on it that says "Based on your service usage history, you are not eligible for quota increase at this time. Please make use of the current available quota, and if additional resources are needed, please contact our Sales Team (https://cloud.google.com/contact/) to discuss further options for higher quota eligibility." when I hover over it.

When I try creating a machine it always fails saying, something about you don't have access to GPUS_ALL_REGIONS...

Comment: Did it work for you eventually? I am facing the same issue right now

Answer (score 1):

When you create resources in Google Cloud, you pay for those resources at the end of the billing cycle (e.g. end of the month). This means that Google Cloud is issuing you credit so that you can billing for services at a later date.

Google has internal rules for the issuance of credit. Your account is not old enough, does not have a payment history, or has other factors that Google uses internally to manage credit, billing, and payments.

One of the methods that Google Cloud implements to manage your credit is to control the type and quantity of resources that you can create. This is accomplished via **quotas**. The quotas for your project are preventing you from using certain resources.

Your solution is to wait until you have an established account. If you are a business, contact a sales account representative and establish a credit line.